# How to add a field to my projected result that is identical to the argument I sent

Tags: mongodb

**[MY MONGOPLAY](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ojPI1mEeooF)**

How can I add a field to my result that is identical to the argument I initially sent. Note in my or statement I'm sending a date and I wish to add this date to my results (example requested_by).

I know that  '$addFields' would do the trick but couldnt figure out how to integrate it.

My Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$match": {
  "$or": [
    {
      "car_id": 78,
      "timestamp": {
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-02-09T00:00:00.000Z")  //NEED THIS PARAMETER in my RESULT
      }
    },
    {
      "car_id": 79,
      "timestamp": {
        "$lte": ISODate("2020-03-22T00:00:00.000Z")   //NEED THIS PARAMETER in my RESULT
      }
    }
  ]
}
},
{
"$sort": {
  "timestamp": 1
}
},
{
"$group": {
  "_id": "$car_id",
  "last": {
    "$last": "$$ROOT"
  }
}
 }
]  )
```

expected result:

```
[
{
"_id": 78,
"last": {
  "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36f0"),
  "car_id": 78,
  "terminal": "LAX",
  "timestamp": ISODate("2020-02-08T17:00:00Z"),
  "requested_by": ISODate("2020-02-09T00:00:00.000Z")  //<--somethign like this
}
},
{
"_id": 79,
"last": {
  "_id": ObjectId("60a2c0621e5f043b735e36f3"),
  "car_id": 79,
  "terminal": "ORD",
  "timestamp": ISODate("2020-03-21T17:00:00Z"),
  "requested_by": ISODate("2020-03-22T00:00:00.000Z")  //<--somethign like this
}
}
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use '$addFields' in your aggregation as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "car_id": 78,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-02-09T00:00:00.000Z")
          }
        },
        {
          "car_id": 79,
          "timestamp": {
            "$lte": ISODate("2020-03-22T00:00:00.000Z")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "timestamp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "requested_by": "something"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$car_id",
      "last": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If your 'requested_by' field should be calculated based on stored value in the object, you can use pipeline operators to calculate its value. For example:

```
  ...
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "requested_by": "$timestamp"
    }
  },
  ...
```

or

```
  ...
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "requested_by": {
        "$add": [
          "$car_id",
          20
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```